# What was the Star Wars parody trailer -- was it "Trash Wars?"

Tags: star-wars

In the late 90's, when *Star Wars* was re-released, I remember seeing a parody *Star Wars* trailer before the movie that was called something like "Trash Wars" that had all the characters looking like shoddy garbage. Does anyone remember what this was called? (searching for "Trash Wars" does not yield any valid results).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### *[Hardware Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_Wars)* is the film you're looking for.

**Characters that tell us this is a *Star Wars* parody:**

- Fluke Starbucker
- Princess Anne-Droid
- Augie "Ben" Doggie
- Ham Salad
- Chewchilla the Wookiee Monster (looks like Cookie Monster)
- Darph Nader

**Objects that give it the "trash" feel":**

- Steam iron (spaceship) feeling a toaster (spaceship) firing toast.
- 4-Q-2 (robot who looks similar to the Tin Man)
- Arty Deco (robot who is a canister vacuum cleaner)
- Cassette player (another spaceship/escape pod)
- Watermelon (standing in for a planet).
- Flashlight (<s>laser sword</s> Lightsaber)
- Steam Cabinets (Imperial Steam Troopers)
- Waffle iron (enemy base)
- Bottle openers (spaceships)

Comment: "feeling" a toaster? :-)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that Hardware wars was made just over a year after A New Hope.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan's answer is probably the correct one, but you may be getting the "garbage" connection from [this spoof series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_%28TV_series%29), *Quark*.  (I'd forgotten about the Bettys...)